# mutate_at function cancels the previous mutate_at

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have created a dataframe S by merging two dataframes innov2015 and innov2017 by a unique identifying column.
Some cases in innov2015 are not included in innov2017 and vice versa, so there are NA entries for half of the variables in S for some of the cases.

I want to calculate p = (p_2015+p_2017)/2 , however, when there is an NA entry for p_2015 I want p = p_2017 and vice versa.

I have tried to do this with:

```
    S <- merge(x = innov_2015_2, y = innov_2017_2, by = "cell_no", all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(p = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(p), funs(ifelse(is.na(smalln_2015), p_2017,(p_2015+p_2017)/2))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(p), funs(ifelse(is.na(smalln_2017), p_2015,(p_2015+p_2017)/2))) %>%
```

If I run

```
    S <- merge(x = innov_2015_2, y = innov_2017_2, by = "cell_no", all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(p = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(p), funs(ifelse(is.na(smalln_2015), p_2017,(p_2015+p_2017)/2))) %>%
```

p takes the desired value.

when I run both mutate_at() statements

```
    S <- merge(x = innov_2015_2, y = innov_2017_2, by = "cell_no", all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(p = 0) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(p), funs(ifelse(is.na(smalln_2015), p_2017,(p_2015+p_2017)/2))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(p), funs(ifelse(is.na(smalln_2017), p_2015,(p_2015+p_2017)/2))) %>%
```

the second mutate_at() statement produces the desired values, however it undoes the first mutate_at() statement and where p had taken the correct value, there is now NA

What do I need to do to make both mutate_at() statements work without cancelling the previous one?

Comment: Why don't you just take the mean of both variables? If one is missing, it takes the mean of 1 value, which is exactly what you want in case not both values are available? Do not forget to specify the `na.rm` argument in the  `mean()` function to `TRUE`. `S %>% mutate(p = mean(c(p_2015,p_2017), na.rm = T))`

Comment: Thanks for the work around, do you know have an explanation for why my code doesn't work? EDIT: the code you have provided inputs the value of p as the mean of the entire columns p_2015 and p_2017 rather than the mean of the values in the corresponding row

Comment: Sorry I meant the `rowMeans()` function above, but can't edit that comment anymore. Anyway, I think your attempt is more of a workaround than my suggestion. Something like: `S$p <- rowMeans(S[,c("p_2015", "p_2017")], na.rm = T)` with just base R would work. The answer below beat me to it with regard to explaining why your attempt did not have the desired result.

Comment: Thanks that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two `mutate`s conflict. You are fully re-defining "p" in each of them, since the value of "p" from the first call is never re-used in the second. @Lennyy's comment will get the job done, but if you want to keep this operation within the **tidyverse**, you might have better luck using `case_when`. Your example is not fully reproducible, so the following is a guess as to how it should work:

```
S <- merge(x = innov_2015_2, y = innov_2017_2, by = "cell_no", all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(p = case_when(
    is.na(smalln_2015) ~ smalln_2017,
    is.na(smalln_2017) ~ smalln_2015,
    TRUE ~ (smalln_2015 + smalln_2017) / 2
  ))
```